why the combined SQL query is slower than the one broken into parts?
I have two queries. They both do the same thing. However, the combined query (the first one) runs a lot slower than the one which is broken down into pieces (the second one). Does anyone know what is the reason for it? Why the query which is broken down into smaller pieces runs faster than a combined one? Any help is appreciated.
I'm using Microsoft SQL Management Studio to run my queries.
Any help is appreciated.
Slower Query
SELECT TBL3.MachineId, TBL3.SoftwareId, TBL3.LicenseId
FROM
(
    select distinct MachineId from 
    (
        select distinct MacineId from MachinesInRegion1
        union all
        select distinct MachineId from MachinesInRegion2
    ) TBL1
) TBL2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MachineId, SoftwareId, LicenseId
    from MachinesInRegion3
) TBL3
ON TBL2.MachineId = TBL3.MachineId

Faster Query
select DISTINCT MachineId
INTO #TBL1 from
(
    select distinct MachineId from MachinesInRegion1
    UNION ALL
    select distinct MachineId from MachinesInRegion2
) TBL1
SELECT MachineId, SoftwareId, LicenseId
INTO #TBL2
from MachinesInRegion3

SELECT * FROM
#TBL1 INNER JOIN #TBL2
ON #TBL1.MachineId = #TBL2.MachineId


A good opportunity to understand Execution plans

While @StephenQuan is correct, I think Microsoft documentation won't get you to understand why. In general, my guess as to the answer would be 'In the first, SQL Server makes bad guesses/estimates regarding the number of records, and therefore chooses bad strategies that take too much time'. I strongly recommend Brent Ozar's excellent training 'How to think like the SQL Server engine' e.g., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMw2knRuIlE and https://www.brentozar.com/training/think-like-sql-server-engine/ - it will take 1-2 hours but will really help you understand how data retrieval works.

You gotta provide your execution plans if you want us to assist (using Paste The Plan)

But the simple answer is that you allow SQL server to create 2 simple execution plans instead of one more complex one. But it may also mean that you are missing indexes or similar that is causing the first query to run slow

In the first query, the optimizer might choose a loop join, hash join, or even a merge join, depending on index availability and statistics. In the second query, it is likely that SQL Server uses a hash join, due to the lack of indexes on the temp tables. It might be the case that the hash join happens to be faster than a loop join for your environment. You can force a particular join type in some situations by adding a join hint keyword - INNER LOOP JOIN or INNER HASH JOIN. (This usage should be limited to cases where the server chooses poorly and you really know what you are doing.)

When running performance tests, you should be aware that cached data in memory can skew test results, giving a later query executions a data access advantage over the initial query execution. To eliminate this variable, you can use the DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS command to wipe in-memory data before each test. (NOTE: this should probably not be done in production database, as it can impact the performance of the associated live application.)

See this db<>fiddle for a demo of the various join types (the original two queries, plus query-hint variations of the first query) showing the resulting execution plans. (Note that the generated plans might be different when run with different data in your environment.). Although db<>fiddle does not permit the use of DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS, the explicit loop join at the end shows the poorest performance this scenario - search for "CpuTime" in the execution plan XML. This does not mean that loop joins are , just that other joins are sometimes faster.
